# jQuery Mobile Dialog reloads the JavaScript from the page it was opened from

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile

When I try to open a dialog it reloads the JavaScript files from the page it was opened from.
The page doesn't refresh, it's only the JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/frameworks/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page" data-role="page">
        <a href="dialog.html" data-rel="dialog" transition="pop" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-inline="true">Open Dialog</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

dialog.html is just a default page, test.js contains:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
    alert("fire");
}
```

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to open a dialog from an external *file.html*.

```
$.mobile.changePage('file.html', { role: 'dialog', transition: 'pop' });
```

It will only load code inside `<body>`.

> **Example**

Button markup

```
<a href="#" id="open-dialog" data-role="button" >Open Dialog</a>
```

Code

```
$('#open-dialog').on('click', function () {
 $.mobile.changePage('file.html', { role: 'dialog', transition: 'pop' });
});
```

Comment: I implemented your code but the outcome is the same: the alert of test.js is shown when opening the dialog.
Could it have to do something with $.mobile.ajaxEnabled?

Comment: @joekeee it should be enabled as it loads the dialog via Ajax.